# Monotone operator subgradient

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

I am trying to solve a PDE of the form $\mathcal{A}u'(t) + \partial\Psi[u(t)] \ni 0$ where $\mathcal{A}$ is a skew-symmetric, linear, monotone operator, $\Psi$ is convex, and $\partial \Psi$ is the subgradient of $\Psi$. All of the references I could find assume $\mathcal{A}$ is symmetric. Do you know of any references which might help me? Thank you.

Comment: If A is invertible this looks to me like a hamiltonian system...